# Angular2 How to open Modelpopup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular2-forms

Please Helpme How can i open Bootstrap Model popup With Help of Ang2 Code

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"(click)="ModelFade()">ModelPopup</button>
    <div *ngIf="visible" >
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I write simple code for *ngIf="visible" as

```
 public visible = false;
    public visibleAnimate = false;
    ModelFade(): void {
        this.visible = true;
        setTimeout(() => this.visibleAnimate = true, 300);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change your html to this it should toggle show / hide.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="visible = visible ? false : true">ModelPopup</button>
        <div *ngIf="visible" >
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: we need to Write any Logic For  visible ?

Comment: can you post or check your css then? for myModal